# stylecop help file not opening

Tags: asp.net, stylecop

i have downloaded the stylecop.chm file...but it is not displaying the content... it only displays index.. nothing is displayed in right pane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows can block CHM files after downloading because they could be potentially harmful.

Just right-click on the file, choose Properties, then press the Unblock button.
http://stylecop.codeplex.com/workitem/6726

Comment: could find any unblock option... i am using windows xp

Answer (score 0):

I download it also and its not work, maybe a bug in the 4.5 preview version help files.

Download an older version, I get it and the older version is work

get it from here:

http://stylecop.codeplex.com/releases/view/48036

Comment: ok found the error -- IE must be installed...jjust formated my system earlier.. so installed IE and it worked..thnx all

Comment: @user685663 well In my computer is still not opening. But the old one is open.

Comment: Hi Aristos ... i downloaded the stylecop.chm again from here
http://stylecop.codeplex.com/releases/view/44839.. even i was unable to open it.. i right-clicked the file and found a unblock security button.. i clicked the unblock button and it worked fine then